# Passing Data in Controllers using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 views in my application. I would like to pass 1st view input to my 2nd view placeholder. I have created a service below

```
.service('greeting', function Greeting() {

    var greeting = this;

greeting.message = 'Default';

})

.controller('LogonController', function LogonController(greeting) {
    var first = this;

    first.greeting = greeting;
})

.controller('VideoController', function VideoController(greeting) {
    var second = this;

    second.greeting = greeting;

});
```

and below are my 2 differents view using different controllers

```
<div ng-controller="LogonController as first">
    <form>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="first.greeting.message" placeholder="{{ first.greeting.message }}"> //1ST VIEW
    </form>
</div>

<div ng-controller="VideoController as second">
    <h1>{{ second.greeting.message }}</h1>
<div> //2ND VIEW
```

I am expecting to get a placeholder with Default message in my 1st form view before i even type my input.

How would i get this to work.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? You won't get the grayed out placeholder text because you also have `data-ng-model="first.greeting.message"` which sets the value of the input.

Comment: What I would like to achieve is to get the input text entered in my 1st view to show on my 2nd view. For example if I enter my name it should show in 2nd view. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: If it's not working for you there must be some kind of error in the console. I just tried the code you provided in JSFiddle and it works fine.

Comment: I am not getting an error in the console. @Lex will you be kind enough and provide me with the JSFiddle link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe whatever browser you are testing this in doesn't like the unclosed `<div>` where you are adding your `VideoController`:

```
<div ng-controller="VideoController as second">
    <h1>{{ second.greeting.message }}</h1>
<div> <-- this should be a closing /div
```

Here is a working version:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="LogonController as first">
        <form>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="first.greeting.message" placeholder="{{ first.greeting.message }}">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="VideoController as second">
        <h1>{{ second.greeting.message }}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .service('greeting', function Greeting() {
        var greeting = this;
        greeting.message = 'Default';
    })
    .controller('LogonController', function LogonController(greeting) {
        var first = this;
        first.greeting = greeting;
    })
    .controller('VideoController', function VideoController(greeting) {
        var second = this;
        second.greeting = greeting;
    });
```

[Working JSFiddle with above](https://jsfiddle.net/2g2xfxhr/)